How to take this basement sink plumbing apart?
The slop sink in the basement is draining poorly and a little water is leaking from the lowest point in the piping under the sink (see photo).  Occasionally there is a glub glub sound coming from the sink when the sink or dishwasher on the first floor is draining.
How do I take this apart so I can snake the drain?
Should I put a wrench on the top fitting by the sink and turn, or do I need to use two wrenches, one placed lower to stop the lower pipe from turning?


WOW!   that's old!   You need pipe wrenches or large locking pliers to turn the nuts.  Some penetrating oil before and prayers.  I would plan on replacing the entire p-trap with some new PVC parts.

@RMDman A channel lock wrench at the top and a pipe wrench on the pipe?  Or two channel lock wrenches, at the top and on the fitting a few inches below that?  Or just a channel lock at the top? I want to reuse the parts.

I would say pipe wrench on the pipe and channel lock on the nuts. I think hoping to reuse the parts may be optimistic.  Good Luck.

You should also get able to just remove the cleanout plug at the bottom of the trap and insert the snake there. It should have facets so you can put a wrench in it. You might want a second pipe wrench to hold the trap steady while you do this.

Yes I would look at the bottom of that trap for a square boss that can be used to unscrew the plug at the bottom of the trap. That said, after decades of corrosion you may never get it loose with normal tools. Start by spraying it down with penetrating oil (WD40 or its ilk) daily for a week or so and then a 24" or longer pipe wrench and lots of weight. If that doesn't break it loose, then it looks like a job for a Sawzall.

The cleanout plug seems to be a large hex nut.  I'll spray it with WD40 today and try to take it apart next week.
